# C# DNS CLASS equivalent in JAVA - GET IPADDRESS in android

Tags: java, c#, android, windows-ce

I m converting C# into JAVA (android) and I m trying to get IP address with help of DNS.

I m trying to get IP address with help of DNS.

```
IPAddress[] addr = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList;
```

How to get the same result in java and which classes should I use?